# Prevent PageExpired

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

i have this problem in my wicket app. i am using wicket 6.13;

This is step by step what happen:

```
- PageA is opened.
- user click on button close twice or more times, clicking on that button cause PageA to be closed and PageB to be opened
- PageExpired occurs
```

First request from the click on the `close` button is executed and `PageA` is closed and `PageB` is opened.
Next request from the click on the `close` button can not find the page in the touch pages so `PageExpired` is thrown.

Any idea how can I prevent the second request from executing so the application can continue to work properly?

Thanks
Sretan

Answer (score 0):

By default PageA should be not only in the `touchedPages` (in memory) but also in the DiskStore (on the hard disk/SSD), so Wicket should be able to find the page by its id.

I am not sure whether 6.13 has it (because it is **very old**) but the Javadoc of PageExpiredException lists [the possible reasons](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/PageExpiredException.java#L31-L33) for this exception:

- the page have never been stored there, e.g. an error occurred during the storing process
- the http session has expired and thus all pages related to this session are erased too
- the page instance has been erased because the store size exceeded

I guess the first reason is the problem in the your case.